# How to resolve internal server error (500) while importing demo content for Wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress

How to resolve internal server error (500) while importing demo content for Wordpress theme?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase memory limit and max execution time parameters.

Try add these constants to your wp-config.php  (before the line define('WP_DEBUG'..)

```
define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

It helps in most cases.

If it doesn't help, you can increate timeout limit too:

```
set_time_limit(0); //remove this after you finish importing
```

If none of these help, it means that your PHP settings are limited and you need to contact your hosting provider support and ask them to increase these limits.

Comment: Thanks Elvin  I was able to import only widget content when adding these constants to wp-config.php. Still this does not work for all theme data.

Comment: Try to increase 256 to 512 in define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' ); string.  If still no luck, you need to turn WP_DEBUG_LOG on and investigate wp-content/debug.log file and see why the process is broken.

Comment: Thanks Elvin for your prompt reply

Answer (score -1):

This is because one of the extensions is missing :

```
sudo apt install php-curl php-gd php-dom php-mbstring php-imagick php-zip
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, please consider expanding on your answer as to why you think this is the relevant solution (this wouldn't be my first idea to solve the problem). While it is great to get answers here on SO, it is even better to learn why a certain solution works!

Comment: I was facing the same error while importing data, and after a health check it turned out that these extensions are missing, after installing them it worked for me!